# ruby on rails how to order by selection box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, select

View:

```
<div>
<%= select_tag(:sorttitle, options_for_select(["title","publish_year"])) %>
<%= select_tag(:sortway, options_for_select(["Order By Asc","Order By Desc"])) %>
<%= submit_tag"Sort Books", class:"btn btn-info"  %>
</div>
```

Model:

```
    if(params[:sortway]=="Order By Desc")
      @books=@books.order(params[:sorttitle]: :desc)
    else
      @books=@books.order(params[:sorttitle]: :asc)
    end
```

Comment: Look into using Ransack https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack

Comment: Is the code you write under "model:" be located in your model's file ? Cause if it's the case it doesnt' seem right. The model file deals with data structure. Do you mean controller instead ?

Answer (score 0):

`@books = @books.order(params[:sorttitle] => :desc)`

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I modified into ur code but met other problems.PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: ...FROM "books" WHERE (title like '%%') ORDER BY "books"."" ASC
                                                                 ^
: SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE (title like '%%') ORDER BY "books"."" ASC

Comment: Looks like you have some bad data in your database - a book that has no title.

Comment: I checked all my data every one has a title. :(